# Strapi register method not allowed 405 in v4 seems url is incorrect

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, strapi

quite puzzled with a Strapi question.  Working with v4 and hooking up a registration functionality.  Invoke code is below. All other things are good i.e. function variables being submitted, etc.  But when I call `strapi.register` I get a 405 All my roles/permissions are good:

```
// make request to register user with strapi
const response = await strapi.register(username, email, password);
```

Result:
`POST http://localhost:1337/auth/local/register 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

When I look in the Strapi admin in the User roles and permissions, I see in the box where the `register` options is that the target url is: `/api/auth/local/register` !!!

What gives?  I read that you may can do something in /config/api.js or similar, or maybe use a proxy in `package.json`. Can't resolve why this url is different?  Is it a bug?  How would you make this work.  I am specultating that I need to add `/api` to the request somewhere.  But don't know where.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the **api/** part.
You should change your path for :

```
  POST  http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local/register
```

Comment: Yes.  I know.  But have no idea where to add this. added it to ./conig/api.js as prefix: "/api"; but doesn't work

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything, just call : POST http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local/register

Comment: Thank you for this. Not a single other resource i could find had /api in the path.